# CSS: elementos de una columna se pongan uno debajo de otro en responsive

Tags: css, responsive

Tengo una landing y estoy haciéndola responsive con css y media queries. Pero estoy atascada con una de las partes. Se compone de un div que a su vez contiene 3 divs colocados en fila y un botón debajo cuando se ve en la pantalla de odenador, pero quiero que a medida que la pantalla se vaya haciendo pequeña estos elementos se coloquen uno debajo de otro. He probado con "display: inline block" pero no me funciona.
¿Alguna idea de por dónde puedo tirar o probar?

Código html:

```
                <h2>Título</h2>

                <div class="ofertas">

                <div class="uno" ><i class="fab fa-wpforms fa-4x" style="margin-left:85px; padding-top:-10px"></i><p style="font-size:18px"> Texto1</p></div>
                <div class="dos" ><i class="far fa-paper-plane fa-4x" style="margin-left:85px; padding-top:-10px"></i><p style="font-size:18px"> Texto2.</p></div>
                <div class="tres" ><i class="fas fa-phone-volume fa-4x" style="margin-left:90px; padding-top:-10px"></i><p style="font-size:18px"> texto3 </p></div>
                
<div class="boton"><a href="#formulario" class="btnblanco">¡Quiero mi oferta!</a></div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
  color: white;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

.uno {
  float: left;
  padding: -90px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dos {
  float: left;
  padding: -90px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tres {
  float: left;
  padding: -90px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.boton {
  position: relative;
  padding: -90px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Si esta usando flexbox, a la clase "ofertas" le asignas las siguientes propiedades:

`.ofertas { display: flex;}`

Automáticamente se alinean una al lado de la otra, pero para que se alineen uno encima de otro debes adicionar la siguiente propiedad:

`.ofertas { display: flex; flex-direction: column;}`

De esta misma forma puedes hacer que en pantallas pequeñas se muestren en columnas y en pantallas grandes en filas

Comment: Gracias! Me sirve.

Comment: @Basileia te recomiendo leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)